# How to excess the array which is inside complex JSON Object?

Tags: angular2-forms, angular2-services

I have a complex JSON Object like this

```
{
    "product": {
        "expiry_type": {
            "type": "premium"
        },
        "accout_holders": {
            "admin": {
                "name": "Admin",
                "description": "Admin"
            }
        },
        "productId": "apple-inc",
        "description": "Apple Incorporation"
    },
    "sales": {
        "datasource": [{
            "name": "USA",
            "type": "direct",
            "uri": "https://www.apple.com/"
        }],
        "apps": {},
        "saleID": "SEIO578ed57EI"
    }
}
```

I got this JSON object by the help of service. 
I want to access the data source and keep it into another array so that I can show the data source name in the angular material chip. How can I access the data source array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its very simple, every JSON Object is given with a name like this:

```js
 {
     "product": {
      "expiry_type": {
       "type": "premium"
      },
      "accout_holders": {
       "admin": {
        "name": "Admin",
        "description": "Admin"
       }
      },
      "productId": "apple-inc",
      "description": "Apple Incorporation"
     },
     "sales": {
      "datasource": [{
       "name": "USA",
       "type": "direct",
       "uri": "https://www.apple.com/"
      }],
      "apps": {},
      "saleID": "SEIO578ed57EI"
     }
    }
```

Now accessing the array which is **datasource** in the above case is done like this
`name.product.sales.datasource[0]`

You don't have to take the datasource to another array in order to show them in a chip. You can iterate your datasource and can use string interpolation for showing any object in an angular material chip. Here is how you can get it.

```html
<mat-chip *ngFor="let ds of name.product.sales.datasource"  matTooltip="{{ds.url}}">
        {{ds.name}}
      </mat-chip>
```

this will display all the datasource **name** object in a chip and if you hover your cursor over the chip you can see **url** as tooltips.